# Space as modifier key XKB

Tags: keyboard, xorg

### Background:

Ultimately, I'm trying to set up a custom one handed keyboard layout similar to [this demo](http://half-qwerty.com/demo/)(click `one-handed typing demo`).

XKB is used in many linux distros. Wikipedia has a decent description of `xkb`.

> In human-computer interfaces, the X keyboard extension or XKB is a
> part of the X Window System that extends the ability to control the
> keyboard over what is offered by the X Window System core protocol.
> The main features of this extension are:

Unfortunately to achieve this functionality I must make the space bar a modifier.

#### The Question:

How would you set up the space key as a modifier in the XKB program?

[http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/html/node3.html](http://www.charvolant.org/%7Edoug/xkb/html/node3.html)

It appears the space is unable to be a modifier by default.

Comment: What in the world is XKB? Questions like this need a *lot* more context...rather than just a [tag:c] tag.

Comment: @CodyGray added some additional context and background behind xkb

Answer (score 5):

I found that [Space2Ctrl](https://github.com/r0adrunner/Space2Ctrl) is a best tool to do this remapping. Very easy, do not require any configuration and works as intended without excess delays. I tried [keydouble](https://github.com/baskerville/keydouble) but it introduced noticeable delay before space was shown on screen

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going to have immense difficulty getting the 'tap to space; hold to shift' behavior.

That said, you can use `xkbcomp :0.0` to dump the current keymap from the server to a file `server-0_0.xkb`, and I *think* I see an easy way to get the space bar to function as as modifier:

```
key <LALT> {         [           Alt_L,          Meta_L ] };
key <SPCE> {         [           space ] };
....
modifier_map Mod1 { <LALT> };
modifier_map Lock { <CAPS> };
```

Try replacing `space` with `Mod5` (or whichever modifier key makes most sense), and then add a new `modifier_map` line:

```
key <LALT> {         [           Alt_L,          Meta_L ] };
key <SPCE> {         [           Meta5 ] };
....
modifier_map Mod1 { <LALT> };
modifier_map Lock { <CAPS> };
modifier_map Meta5 { <SPCE> };
```

This is untested, but it *feels* right.

I don't know how you'll get a plain old *space* though. I'd suggest mapping it to another key entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [keydouble](https://github.com/baskerville/keydouble). It's a user-space utility that attaches itself to X and continues to grab and processes keyboard events. The default configuration provided in `examples/keydoublerc` does exactly what you want - space becomes ctrl. If it is not used with another key then space is inserted upon key release.