# How to map space to control and unmap win from Hyper_L using xkb/setxkbmap

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap, xkb, setxkbmap

I am trying to make my space act as control by default (and as space when tapped by using [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape)) and to make capslock act as the only hyper modifier. I have a working configuration for this in xmodmap, but it keep resetting randomly, so I have to restart it manually every now and then which is annoying.

I have read that xkb is the way to go nowadays, but I completely fail in figuring out how to remap keys that do not have predefined rules accessible via `setxkbmap -option`. There is no such rule to remap space to control and while there is one to remap caps to hyper, my win keys are already mapped to hyper so when I press caps it somehow invokes hyper and super, which is also bound to my win key. I had a similar problem with xmodmap, which I got around by clearing the hyper modifier from all other keys, but I can't figure out how to do this in xkb.

I have seen [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/371150/space-as-modifier-key-xkb) and tried dumping the xkbcomp file and changing space to Control_L, but it did not work. I used the following sequence for that.

```
xkbcomp $DISPLAY xkb.dump
vi xkb.dump
xkbcomp xkb.dump $DISPLAY
```

Maybe there are others configuration files to edit? I am a little lost at the moment, the `setxkbmap -option` is super easy, but beyond there seems to be quite the jungle, so some guidance would be great.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with default unity.